# dynamic SQL update command

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I am using MSSQL 2016,

I need to be able to update a row on a table dynamically.

I got a stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_lookupData_UpdatelookupValues
 (
 @FullTableName nvarchar(50), 
 @Id nvarchar(10),
 @Name nvarchar(50),
 @Description nvarchar(50)
 )
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Cmd nvarchar(150) = N'UPDATE ' + @FullTableName + ' SET Name = ' +  @Name  + ', Description = ' + @Description + ' WHERE ID = ' + @Id + '';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Cmd;

END
```

The problem is that Name and Description values are passed into the @Cmd like this :

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET Name = Private, Description = Default WHERE ID = 1
```

Instead of 'Private'  and 'Default'.

The result is an error where Private is being counted as a column which doesnt exist ( because of the bad format ).

```
Invalid column name 'Private'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Put the quotes yourself

Use single quotes around `Private` and `Default`.
And since you are using dynamic querying, you have to double the single quotes to escape them.

```
DECLARE @Cmd nvarchar(150) = N'UPDATE ' + @FullTableName + ' SET Name = ''' +  @Name  + ''', Description = ''' + @Description + ''' WHERE ID = ' + @Id + '';
```

Also make sure you try the next solution, since the first one is SQL Injection compatible.

## Use sp_executesql parameters

You can also use the parameters inside your `@Cmd` without doing the concatenation yourself but by passing the parameters to `sp_executesql`

Also I suggest you to `QUOTENAME` the `@FullTableName` parameter in case of spaces inside table's name.

```
DECLARE @Cmd nvarchar(150) = N'UPDATE QUOTENAME(@FullTableName) SET Name = @Name, Description = @Description WHERE ID = @Id;'
EXEC sp_executesql @Cmd, @FullTableName, @Name, @Description, @Id;
```

The advantage doing so, is you avoid any parameters not checked by the application to be able to do SQL Injection.

### Reference :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

Comment: If you use such code, you should secure against SQL-injection by replacing ' with ''. And if your concept requires doing something like this, you should question the concept in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the quotes yourself. I prefer to use [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to keep all the quotes recognizable:

```
QUOTENAME(@FullTableName, '''')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use parameters for identifiers.  But, you can use parameters for values:

```
DECLARE @Cmd nvarchar(150) = N'
UPDATE ' + @FullTableName + '
    SET Name = @Name,
        Description = @Description 
WHERE ID = @Id';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Cmd,
        N'@Name nvarchar(50), @Description nvarchar(50), @Id nvarchar(10)',
        @Name = @Name, @Description = @Description, @Id = @id;
```

Unfortunately, the dynamic table name still poses risks, both in terms of SQL injection and syntax errors.  I am guessing this is "controlled" code, not code with user input, so the risks might be acceptable.  However, you probably should use `quotename()`.

That brings up another issue which is probably the crux of the problem.  Why do you have multiple tables with the same columns?  Could these -- should these -- all be stored in a single table?  This type of code calls into question aspects of the data model.